# Clarify on Krull dimension and integrality

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, integral-extensions

Let $f:A\to B$ be a homomorphism of rings, and let $I:=\operatorname{ker} f$.

> If $f$ is surjective, $\operatorname{dim}A\ge\operatorname{dim} B$.

I'd say that this holds because a chain of prime ideals, in $A/I$, yields a chain of prime ideals in $A$ via contraction. Since the contraction induces a bijection in this case, the inclusions of the chain in $A$ remain strict.

> If $f$ is integral and injective, $\operatorname{dim}B\ge\operatorname{dim} A$.

This should be a consequence of the going-up theorem, for any chain of prime ideals in $A$ yields a chain of prime ideals in $B$, and again the inclusions stay strict.

> If $f$ is integral, $\operatorname{dim}B\ge\operatorname{dim} A$.

This I don't know. We have that $A/I\to B$ is an integral injection, so $\operatorname {dim} B\ge \operatorname{dim} A/I$. However also $\operatorname {dim} A\ge \operatorname {dim} A/I$, so I don't know how I could deduce the thesis. Is it actually true? (I took the exercise from a paper where I already found some typos). If it is, could you give me only a hint to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is integral and injective we have that $A≃f(A)⊂B$ is integral and thus $\dim A=\dim B$.

For similar reasons, in the third case we have $\dim B\le\dim A$.

Comment: I'm sorry to be this confused, but as you say in the second case we could write directly that $A\subseteq B$ integral; doesn't this only imply that a chain in $A$ induces a chain in $B$? If I start with a chain in $B$, even if $A\subseteq B$ is integral, it is not said that the contracted chain in $A$ is made again all of different ideals (or it is said?). Anyway I just found this exercise (only the third part) on Bosch's Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra too (it is the 3.3.2)

Comment: I see that proposition 3.3.6 on Bosch's book says that $f$ injective and integral implies $\operatorname{dim}A=\operatorname{dim}B$, so don't mind about that part, the proof will clarify it. However I can't still see why the third point holds

Comment: In the third case $\dim B=\dim f(A)$ since $f(A)\subset B$ is integral. But $\dim f(A)\le\dim A$.

Comment: Your argument is clear,  but understand my concern; does the exercise on Bosch have a typo? (In case you don't have the book,  it says:  *Let $R\to R′$ be an integral morphism of rings. Show $\operatorname{dim} R \le \operatorname{dim} R'$*. Isn't it exactly the third point?

Comment: I don't have Bosch book at hand, but let's see what others say: https://books.google.ro/books?id=NnD-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=integral+morphism+dim+A+dim+B&source=bl&ots=1g-CxwSz7c&sig=ACfU3U0UcgV-OaUVb_LJxHSGC5kVBRS_jA&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_zo2brLz1AhUP-6QKHb9nAooQ6AF6BAgwEAI#v=onepage&q=integral%20morphism%20dim%20A%20dim%20B&f=false